# Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libboost.so" not found

Tags: android, flutter

I run a example code for flutter in my device. 
And I get a log:

```
2019-03-28 10:07:18.105 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.322 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example I/chatty: uid=10481(com.example.ijkplayer_example) Thread-4 identical 12 lines
2019-03-28 10:07:18.341 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.365 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.377 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example I/chatty: uid=10481(com.example.ijkplayer_example) Thread-4 identical 1 line
2019-03-28 10:07:18.397 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.409 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.417 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.434 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
2019-03-28 10:07:18.735 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example I/chatty: uid=10481(com.example.ijkplayer_example) Thread-4 identical 17 lines
2019-03-28 10:07:18.739 6794-6819/com.example.ijkplayer_example E/FPS-BOOST: notifyQueue load error
```

Before this log appears, there will be one:

> Can't load library: dlopen failed: library "libboost.so" not found.

But I didn't use the library in my code. I find flutter code, flutter framework and engine, also not find it.

```sh
flutter create example_code
cd example code
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **ndk** configuration in your **app folder build.gradle** file **defaultConfig** section.
This may be help you.

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ex"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        ndk {
            // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a"
           // abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not helpful. Normally flutter projects don't include this library.